# bootbox confirm - include href when OK is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, bootbox

I am trying to add in [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) to a test page.

Currently, when I include the href tag in the hyperlink that triggers the bootbox, the href is triggered regardless of what confirm button I click (Cancel or OK).

**How do I include the href tag into the bootbox js code to be triggered only when the user selects the OK confirm option?** I have tried several attempts, but to no avail.

Here is the hyperlink with the href tag:

```
<a id="id_customized_details_duplicate" href="{% url customized_details_duplicate customized_detail.id %}">Duplicate</a>
```

Here is my bookbox js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id_customized_details_duplicate').on('click', function(){
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    //include the href duplication link here?;
                    //showProgressAnimation();
                    alert('OK SELECTED');
                } else {
                    alert('CANCEL SELECTED');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way, prevent the default action of the `anchor tag` & add window redirection call with respective `href` location within the `bootbox` confirmation handler(when 'OK' option clicked).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_customized_details_duplicate').on('click', function(event){
                   event.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                 //include the href duplication link here?;
                 window.location = $(this).attr("href");

                //showProgressAnimation();
                alert('OK SELECTED');
            } else {
                alert('CANCEL SELECTED');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/9he30z4y/255/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I have been tinkering with it for some hours now because the window.location = $(this).attr("href"); line of code does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1261774: could you create a jsfiddle, i`ll check it there

Comment: @user1261774: its working as intended here, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/gvK5t/.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have it working now - thanks to your jfiddle.

Comment: jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: @JoshYates1980 : not sure why jsfiddle link is broken, but anyway i have fixed now. http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/9he30z4y/255/. thanks for letting me know :)